# Is there a way to set a typealias of a protocol's associated type in a sub protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols, covariant-return-types

I didn't see this in the similar questions, so I think this is unique. I have a protocol

```
protocol Zot {}

protocol Foo {
    associatedType Bar: Zot
    var prop1: Bar { get set }
}
```

Now I could say

```
class Zoty: Zot {}

class Fooy: Foo {
    typealias Bar = Zoty
    var prop1: Zoty = Zoty()
}
```

But I haven't quite moved to the class layer yet. Is there a way for me to set the type alias in a protocol like so?

```
protocol Fooie: Foo {
    typealias Bar = Zoty
    var prop1: Zoty { get set }
}
```

The compiler says to make it like this

```
protocol Fooie: Foo where Bar == Zoty {
    var prop1: Bar { get set }
}
```

But then it throws the error `Cannot override mutable property 'prop1' of type 'Self.Bar' with covariant type 'Zoty'`

Comment: In my project, `prop1` is a `ModelController`. There are a number of different model controllers though. I have a resolver which is supposed to pull in a number of objects which hold the model controller. Each of those objects conforms to a subprotocol of `Foo`, but I want the resolver to have access to a function on the model controllers to help reset them.

I was going to just iterate through a list of Foo conforming objects because I wasn't sure how to use the protocol delegate approach. I could also use notification center, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error, just remove this line in `Fooie`

```
var prop1: Bar { get set }
```

You do not need to redeclare this again, and I do agree the error message is a bit confusing. Swift thinks that you are trying to override the property, which as far as it is concerned, is declared to be a different type, but in this context, the two types can only be the same.

After removing the property, you can now do:

```
class Fooy: Fooie {
    var prop1 = Zoty()
}
```

and this gives errors

```
class SomethingElse: Zot {}

class Fooy: Fooie {
    var prop1 = SomethingElse()
}
```

> 'Fooie' requires the types 'SomethingElse' and 'Zoty' be equivalent

> Type 'Fooy' does not conform to protocol 'Fooie'

Comment: I think this almost solves the issue. I have a resolver which is trying to resolve a number of `Foo` conforming protocols. Say `Fooie`, `Foo2`, `Foo3` etc... When I have something like `var fooie: Fooie`, I get the error `Protocol 'Fooie' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. Which... I guess makes this an XY problem. Sorry

Comment: @TinyTim Where is `fooie` declared? In any case, it should be `var fooie: any Fooie`, right?

Comment: For some reason, `any` doesn't seem to work for me, but `some` does. Although, `some` seems to want to require an immediate initializer, as in, I can't set it in the `init()`

Comment: I just checked, Swift 5.6.1

Comment: @TinyTim Okay, perhaps I remembered wrong. I'm using Swift 5.7, and `var fooie: any Fooie` works for me, so I guess try updating to 5.7.

Comment: Looks like `any` was added in 5.6, but I may be running a buggy version. I'll update. I've been holding back for a bit so that most of the bugs of the released software would get worked out. Had a coworker update his laptop and it become incompatible with our setup for a bit. thanks for your help Sweeper!

Comment: @TinyTim I think it needs [this feature](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0352-implicit-open-existentials.md), which is indeed implemented in 5.7.

Comment: Yep, you right. Updating to Ventura now. Gonna go whole hog and update everything. Funny how the feature I need is available just when I needed it. Recent release too, I feel lucky! Thanks again Sweeper, happy holidays!